# The Android Studio Project Synchronization Is Slow After the HMS Core Is Connected

Tags: huawei-mobile-services

I have configured Google and center Maven repositories. But it shows that they are not configured, what should I do?

Comment: Please be more specific. [https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

In the case of what you described, all dependency packages of the project will be synchronized to the Maven repository of Huawei first. As a result, the synchronization speed is slow.
If you find that project synchronization is slow, configure the Maven repository in the following sequence:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'http://developer.huawei.com/repo/'
        }
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'http://developer.huawei.com/repo/'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Having a separate repository section will help speed up the build.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'http://developer.huawei.com/repo/'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can speed up by specifying the maven's groups. Add this maven as the last source in `gradle.properties`:

```
maven {
    url 'http://developer.huawei.com/repo/'
    content {
        includeGroup "com.huawei"
        includeGroup "com.huawei.hms"
        includeGroup "com.huawei.agconnect"
        includeGroup "com.huawei.hmf"
    }
}
```

The result would be:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'http://developer.huawei.com/repo/'
            content {
                includeGroup "com.huawei"
                includeGroup "com.huawei.hms"
                includeGroup "com.huawei.agconnect"
                includeGroup "com.huawei.hmf"
            }
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3'
        classpath 'com.huawei.agconnect:agcp:1.2.0.300'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'http://developer.huawei.com/repo/'
            content {
                includeGroup "com.huawei"
                includeGroup "com.huawei.hms"
                includeGroup "com.huawei.agconnect"
                includeGroup "com.huawei.hmf"
            }
        }
    }
}
```